# How to break out Board to FPC connector

Tags: embedded, connector

I'm trying to (hopefully) reuse a smartphone LCD and touchscreen controller, among some other components.

The first step is to break out the tiny connectors on the board. It appears to be 2 board to FPC connections. See picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jctIv.jpg (bottom right, sorry for the poor quality)

I found this [resource](http://pewa.panasonic.com/components/connectors/narrow-pitch-board-to-fpc-connectors/a35s/) but it's almost impossible for me to tell which one specifically is used.

Any suggestions for how I could get to those signals or wire it up to a breadboard?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Is soldering wire leads to the connector not an option?

Comment: Not unless I was an inch tall. They're much too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These type of connectors are usually called fine pitch board-to-board connectors. I doubt that you'll really find a way to connect to them without having to solder small wire leads. With the right tools, it's not as hard as you think. You'll need some fine gauge wire (wire-wrap works great), magnification, and a soldering iron with a sharp tip. With a little practice, I'm sure you can do it!